# directory index of "/opt/eds/web/html" is forbidden

Tags: nginx

To configure nginx, as follows

```
location ~ "^/[A-Z0-9]{32}" {
 alias /opt/eds/web/html;
 index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

nginx Abnormal log

```
`2019/12/17 23:22:56 [error] 28874#28874: *4 directory index of "/opt/eds/web/html" is forbidden`
```

but modify nginx configuration, as follows

```
location /25DE5ADF310211E9BDB874D435BEC0BA {
 alias /opt/eds/web/html;
 index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

No problem with access

Answer (score 0):

When `alias` is used with a regular expression `location`, you need to capture the remainder of URI and append it on the `alias` value.

For example:

```
location ~ "^/[A-Z0-9]{32}(/.*)?$" {
    alias /opt/eds/web/html$1;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.